# Display custom user profile fields in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hook

I am new to wordpress development. I was trying to solve the problem of adding extra fields to my wordpress user profile area. I achieved this with a plugin. How do I call the value of these fields on my custom dashboard page template for logged in users, like so: `<a href=""><?php echo $profile_field_name ?></a>`.

Comment: What plugin you have used to add custom fields?

Comment: @jogesh_pi, I used Profile Extra fields plugin

Answer (score 1):

You can use get_user_meta Function. for exp in your case :

```
$profile_field_name = '';    
if (get_user_meta( $user_id, 'profile_field_name', true )){
     $profile_field_name = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'profile_field_name', true );
    };
```

then you can echo like your example :

```
<a href=""><?php echo $profile_field_name ?></a>
```

Comment: Thanks james for stopping by; should my ```profile_field_name``` in your ```get_user_meta( $user_id, 'profile_field_name', true )```  function be these names <https://prnt.sc/wa47p9> explicitly? I used a plugin to add the fields dont forget